# Problem with Python interpreter in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ubuntu, interpreter

When trying to set the interpreter for python in Eclipse by choosing the executable, clicking OK displays "An error has occured." Does the interpreter name matter?

Comment: Could you provide more detail on what steps you did? What version of Python and Pydev are you using?

Comment: Additionally, you can find more details about the error by selecting Window->Show View->Error Log

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problems with this on Mac OS X. My problem was that I had a space in Eclipse's application path, e.g. "/Applications/eclipse 3.3/Eclipse".

I changed the folder name to "/Applications/eclipse3.3" and it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Testing/running your apps on the command line is the safest bet, especially when writing threaded applications (you can kill your threadlocked program without killing eclipse)